# Android intent to open URL in same tab in google chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent, google-chrome-app

Google chrome opens URL in new tab when chrome app is killed.
Following code is being used.It open URL in same tab if chrome app is not killed otherwise it opens URL in new tab.

```
String urlString = "https://www.google.com/";
Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlString));
intent1.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID, "com.android.chrome");
intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent1.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
```

The URL should be opened in chrome in a single tab.

Answer (score 5):

Use **EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID** with your intent to make sure that same browser tab is reused for your app. For example:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Browser.html#

For Example

```
Context context = widget.getContext();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
intent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID, context.getPackageName());
```